# Combining two arrays PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm busy with sorting the structure of a menu in my application. Once the menu is reorderd by the user, the values (say; Menu item 1, Menu item 2, etc) are still in the same place.

Now I have two arrays, one that holds the way they are sorted (Array 1) and one that holds the values of the menu items. (Array 2)

Example of both arrays;
(Array 1, that holds the keys)

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 0
)
```

The above array's values are the keys for the new array.

(Array 2, holds the values)

```
Array
(
    [0] => value_0
    [1] => value_1
    [2] => value_2
)
```

So I thought it would be best to create a new array which consist out of;

1. The values of Array 1
2. The values of Array 2

However, i'm running into a problem. I want the values in array 2 to stick to their keys. So lets say I change the position of value_0 to the last, the new array would look like this;

```
Array
(
    [1] => value_1
    [2] => value_2
    [0] => value_0
)
```

Is there a way to achieve this or am I doing it completely wrong?

**Edit**

Ok, so multidemensional array it is. However i'm having problems creating one.

Array 1 and Array 2 both come from the database. Array 1 with the sorting order and Array 2 contains the values. Now, the values in array 2 are stored like this; value1,value2,value3. So to be able to work with them I explode on , (comma).

The results on the fetchs are both different;

- For the first array it returns as many as how many values there are.
  (So if there are 3 values, it will return 3 different positions.)
- For the second array it will return 18 records, since this is tied to
  other menu items (sub menu's etc).

So for the first array I do;

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_query_test)) {
       $positions[] = $row['position'];
  }
```

For the second array I do;

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_values)) {
      $array_values = explode(',', $row['values']);
}
```

From then on i'm having problems creating the multidimensinonal array;

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_values)) {
     $array_values = explode(',', $row['values']);
     foreach ($positions as $new_key) {
         foreach ($array_values as $value) {
              $new_array[] = array('key' => $new_key, 'value' => $value);
         }
     }
}
```

**Edit two:**

This is what I use now;

(Since $all_values is a multidimensional array because I have to explode on the values beforehand.)

```
    foreach ($all_values as $values) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $new_array[] = array('key' => $positions[$key], 'value' => $value);
        }
    }
```

This is what the $new_array returns;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => 0
            [value] => value_0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => 2
            [value] => value_2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1
            [value] => value_1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [key] => 0
            [value] => value_0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [key] => 2
            [value] => value_2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1
            [value] => value_1
        )
```

Now I need to get the values and implode them with comma's. However, since not every 3 values (value_0, value_1, value_3) are together I can't do that now.

In this example there are 3 keys, (0,1,2) which should be a different array along with their values, like you did in your example:

```
Array (
  [0] = Array (
    [key] = 1,
    [value] = value_1
  ),
  [1] = Array (
    [key] = 2,
    [value] = value_2
  ),
  [2] = Array (
    [key] = 0,
    [value] = value_0
  )
)
```

Comment: If i understand this correctly you want a nested list?

Comment: consider a 2-dimensional array? http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php

Comment: Or no array... :P By using [left] and [right]

Comment: Can you show us all the code to make the last array, including the `SELECT` statements?

Comment: Can you show what is held in `$all_values`? I think you only need to use a piece of it and not the whole thing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @iQ722 I added an implode to my answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make a multidimensional array?

```
$arrayThree = 
Array (
  [0] = Array (
    [key] = 1,
    [value] = value_1
  ),
  [1] = Array (
    [key] = 2,
    [value] = value_2
  ),
  [2] = Array (
    [key] = 0,
    [value] = value_0
  )
)
```

No matter what order they're in, the key and value are always the set.

```
foreach ($arrayThree as $tempArray)
{
 echo $tempArray['key'];
 echo $tempArray['value'];
}
```

**Create Array**

```
$arrayOne = array();
$arrayTwo = array();
$arrayThree = array();

$query = 'SELECT key FROM table1 ';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $arrayOne[] = $data['key'];
}

$query = 'SELECT value FROM table2 ';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $arrayTwo[] = $data['value'];
}

foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value)
{
  $arrayThree[] = array('key' => $value, 'value' => $arrayTwo[$key]);
}
```

You can always use the mysqli or PDO versions, if you're using them.

**Example Data**

```
    //THESE MIMIC YOUR SELECT RESULTS
$test_keys = array(1,2,3);
$test_values = array('value_1', 'value_2', 'value_3');

    //DEFAULTS
$arrayOne = array();
$arrayTwo = array();
$arrayThree = array();

    //WHILE FIRST SELECT
for($i=0;$i<count($test_keys);$i++)
{
    $arrayOne[] = $test_keys[$i];
}

    //WHILE SECOND SELECT
for($i=0;$i<count($test_values);$i++)
{
    $arrayTwo[] = $test_values[$i];
}

    //MAKE THE FINAL ARRAY
foreach($arrayOne as $key => $value)
{
  $arrayThree[] = array('key' => $value, 'value' => $arrayTwo[$key]);
}

    //CHECK THE OUTPUT FOR THE NEW ARRAY
echo '<pre>'.print_r($arrayThree,true).'</pre>';
```

**Example Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => 1
            [value] => value_1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => 2
            [value] => value_2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key] => 3
            [value] => value_3
        )

)
```

**Imploded List**

```
$implodeValues = array_map(function($item) { return $item['value']; }, $arrayThree);
$implodeVariable = implode(',', $implodeValues);

echo $implodeVariable;
```

**Implode Output**

`value_1,value_2,value_3`

Comment: Thanks for the example. I kinda have a problem creating the multidimensional array. Both arrays (Array 1 and 2) are coming from the database. Array 1 with the sorting order works fine, however Array 2 is a array that comes from the explode function. (This is because the values are stored like this in the database; value1,value2,value3,etc.)

I'll edit my post to show what's going on.

Comment: I added a simple select part to the bottom of my answer. If you're getting them from multiple tables, let me know.

Comment: I am using multiple tables. The values are stored like this (in the database); value1,value2,value3,etc. So I need to explode them on , (comma). 
Now one thing I know is, the amount of values, so if i stay on my example, value1,value2,value3 are 3. Which is always the same to the sorting order. If that makes any sense. That's basically what i'm stuck on.

Comment: Are you able to `JOIN` the tables and use one query? - edited answer to show a, very simple, `JOIN` query. I am not sure the exact structure.

Comment: No I am not able to use a JOIN on them. Structure is basically like this; Table with values; value_id, value_desc. Sorting table; sort_id, sort_num. Narrowed down version. For now i'm using two different SELECT s.

Comment: Look at the building array part of my answer and see if it is something that you can use. The two queries will need to be sorted the same way to avoid mismatching the data.

Comment: I've got it working, somewhat. Thanks alot! Only problem now is, since   I need to explode on the values secondArray (using your example) I get a multidimensional array back. I'll edit my post to show what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can obtain what you want doing this:

```
$new = array();
for($i = 0, $len = count($array1), $i < $len, ++$i) {
    $new[$array1[$i]] = $array2[$i];
}
```

now `$new` contains the values in the order you want them

Comment: Your method isn't giving me the correct keys with the corresponding values.

Comment: Yes, I see you're right: considering `$array1 = array(1, 2, 0)` and `$array2 = array('value_0', 'value_1', 'value_2')` this script yields `$new = array(1 => 'value_0', 2 => 'value_1', 0 => 'value_2')`... Sorry for the wrong suggestion, I think you're best suited using the multidimensional array as suggested.